# Grunt hangs during build

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to run a `grunt build` and when it gets to the following:

```
Running tasks: compass:dist

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: sassDir="src/assets/styles", cssDir=".tmp/styles", generatedImagesDir="dist/images/generated", imagesDir="src/assets/images", javascriptsDir="src/app", fontsDir="src/assets/styles/fonts", importPath="./bower_components", httpImagesPath="/images", httpGeneratedImagesPath="/images/generated", httpFontsPath="/styles/fonts", relativeAssets=false, assetCacheBuster=false, raw="Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\r\n"
directory .tmp/styles
    write .tmp/styles/main.css (4.122s)

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-12-28 22:43:20 UTC)
loading tasks   9ms  0%
compass:dist   5.6s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 100%
Total 5.6s
```

It hangs there forever and never completes. I am not very good with Grunt and don't know how to begin troubleshooting this. Any advice/direction would be helpful.

EDIT: Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
// Generated on 2015-06-09 using generator-angular 0.9.0-1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Configurable paths for the application
    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'src',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: appConfig,

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/app/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                }
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: {
                src: [
                    'Gruntfile.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/{,*/}*.js'
                ]
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
                },
                src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath: new RegExp('^<%= yeoman.app %>/|../')
            },
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                ignorePath: /(\.\.\/)(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
            }
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/app',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/styles/fonts',
                importPath: './bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false,
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat'], // ['concat', 'uglifyjs']
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
            }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //   dist: {}
        // },

        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: false,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/app',
                    //src: ['*.html', '/*/*.html'],
                    src: '**/*.html',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/app'
                }]

                //,deploy: {
                //    options: {
                //        collapseWhitespace: true
                //    },
                //    files: [{
                //        expand: true,
                //        cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                //        src: ['*.html', 'app/*.html'],
                //        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                //    }]
                //}

            }
        },

        // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
        // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
        // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        '*.html',
                        'app/views/{,*/}*.html',
                        'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                        'assets/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts',
                    src: '**/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/fonts'
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './bower_components/font-awesome',
                    src: 'fonts/**',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets'
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass:server'
            ],
            test: [
                'compass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'compass:dist',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        },

        // DefinitelyTyped mappings.
        tsd: {
            refresh: {
                options: {
                    command: 'reinstall',
                    latest: true,
                    config: './tsd.json',
                    opts: {
                        // props from tsd.Options
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-tsd');

    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'wiredep',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'tsd:refresh',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        /*'ngmin',*/
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        /*'uglify',*/
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your full Gruntfile please?

Comment: can you run grunt command with --verbose i.e. `grunt --verbose` and check complete output

Comment: I am not able to. SO only allows 30,000 characters. Pasting the full output results in over 40,000. At the top of my post is the last part of the verbose output. That is where the build just...stops. And it stays there. Forever.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue an after a while I found that htmlmin was hanging because of an invalid tag on one html file.

Try to run:

> grunt htmlmin --verbose

If that it is hanging you should see the name of the html file with problems.

After that try to find the issue, on your file, using one [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options).